# Making a quest system in a game. Is there a way to hide the next quest

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a quest system in my clicker game. I don't want each of the quests to be flat out on the page:

[image]

I'd like the user to be like "Oh cool this was hidden and it is only revealed once you have a certain amount of quests done". Then I want there to be rewards like a special sword or something. I mostly want to know how in HTML you can hide things from being on the screen until a condition is met.

Haven't tried anything new to HTML/ JavaScript

This is my HTML code: (don't have any JavaScript for this part yet but if I can get some examples on how to hide stuff id appreciate it)

```
 Quests
 <br/>
 Click 1000 times <span id="Numberofclicks">0</span>
 <span id="Maxnumberofclicks">1000</span>
 <br/>
 Use skills 50 times <span id="Spelluses">0</span>
 <span id="Maxspelluses">50</span>
 <br/>
```

I expect the quests: "Numberofclicks" and "Spelluses" to stay hidden until those quests are completed or a certain amount of quests are finished. My actual output is nothing yet because I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Where's the JS?

Comment: I posted I don't have any javascript. I asked for examples on how this works. Im new at this so I have no idea how to format the javascript

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this is pretty simplistic.

But we can click quests and the reveal rewards.

Note how the `CSS` hides `.reward` items by default.

```js
const questClicks = {};

const questClick = ({dataset: {count: c, reward : r}}) => {
  questClicks[r] += 1;
  if(questClicks[r] >= c) document.querySelector(`#${r}`).style.display = 'block';
};

document.addEventListener('click', ({target}) => {
  if(target.matches('.quest')) {
    questClick(target);
  }
});

// Init all quests
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.quest').forEach(({dataset: { reward: r }}) => questClicks[r] = 0);
});
```

```css
.clicker {
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.reward {
  display: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id='sword-quest' class='quest' data-count='5' data-reward='sword'>Click Me Lots !!</div>
<div class='reward' id='sword'>Here is a sword</div>

<div id='shield-quest' class='quest' data-count='3' data-reward='shield'>Click Me Lots !!</div>
<div class='reward' id='shield'>Here is a sword</div>
```

Comment: so you have to use css to hide content? Ill give this a try but i saw this on a website https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp  Idk if this is diffrent but if it can work to hide a quest until ( mabey ill do amount of quests finished) quests >=2 . Its just javascript code i think

Comment: Yes, I would recommend using CSS in modern coding.